# What does frame_dummy mean in the context of profiling?

Tags: c++, g++, profiling

In the process of using gprof to profile a C++ program I've written, I've noticed that the vast majority of execution time is spent in the function "frame_dummy". More precisely, the first entry in the flat profile from the output of gprof shows 76.38% of sample time spent in and 24611191 calls to a function with name frame_dummy.

In short, I am trying to understand both what frame_dummy refers to -- as I do not have any function named as such -- as well as what this means for my optimization efforts.

Though it is unlikely to be relevant, I should add that this program is designed to solve Poisson's equation using the multigrid algorithm, and employs MPI to parallelize the task. However, though MPI function calls are present, the gprof output mentioned above is derived from running only a single process. I should also note that my program has no dependencies aside from MPI and was compiled with g++ 4.6.1.

Comment: It's part of the C runtime library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a very good explanation here: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html .  But I'm not sure why your program would spend so much time in frame_dummy, or why it would get called so many times.

Perhaps the debug info in your binary is corrupt in some way, or is getting misread by gprof?  Or gprof might get confsued by MPI?  Here's something to try: run your program in gdb, and with a breakpoint on the frame_dummy function.  See whether it really gets called 24 million times, and if it does, then what it's getting called from.

Also, can you confirm that this is the frame_dummy in crtbegin.o, and not some other frame_dummy?

Here's [the source for frame_dummy in crtbegin.c](http://code.google.com/p/nacl-thumb2/source/browse/src/third_party/crt/crtbegin.c?spec=svn6f45988698c7ec0be175e263d6e6654e3c67c68a&r=6f45988698c7ec0be175e263d6e6654e3c67c68a) -- by my reading of the code, it should only get called once.

Also, I'm assuming that your program runs and produces the correct result?  (In particular, if there's a memory bug in your program, then you can get some pretty odd behavior.)

Comment: Edward, how gprof finds a function name? May be John not added `-pg` option to his own program compilation; but added it to linking step. `crtbegin` with `-pg` was used; but no calls to the gprof instrumentation in his code.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! I ultimately discovered the same phenomenon that Joel mentioned; compiling with -O3 performs some kind of optimization that causes gprof to read several frequently called functions as calls to frame_dummy.

Comment: I had a similar problem today. Upgrading from g++ 4.4 to g++ 4.6 introduced some `frame_dummy` time.  It appears newer version of g++ do different/more-aggressive optimization when -O3 is in effect.  I didn't notice this problem with v4.4.  After switching to `-Os` I noticed some funcs that had some asserts in them.  When I removed the asserts, those functions became much faster and didn't contribute to `frame_dummy`.

Comment: For me, `gprof` was being confused by my use of `-fopenmp`,  if I removed OpenMP,  `frame_dummy` disappeared.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue, here is my output from gprof:

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 52.00     16.27    16.27   204000     0.08     0.08  frame_dummy
 47.46     31.12    14.85   418000     0.04     0.07  f2
  0.51     31.28     0.16    21800     0.01     1.42  f1
  0.03     31.29     0.01     1980     0.01    14.21  f5
```

In my case, it got resolved when I compiled with `gcc -Os` instead of `gcc -O3`:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 53.12     22.24    22.24   200000     0.11     0.11  f4
 45.65     41.36    19.11   598000     0.03     0.03  f2
  0.69     41.65     0.29    20000     0.01     1.45  f3
  0.45     41.84     0.19    39800     0.00     0.32  f1
  0.10     41.88     0.04                             evaluate
```

That is, gprof mistook `f4` for `frame_dummy`.

Comment: This is it exactly what the problem was, though in fact it seemed that several different functions were being subsumed by frame_dummy. It's a bit frustrating, though, because turning off optimizations dramatically changes the profile structure as functions are affected to differing degrees by compiler optimization.