# fortran erroneously calls a subroutine

Tags: fortran, profiling, linear-algebra, fortran90

I have some Fortran 90 code that I've been using for finite element computations. Lately, I've been trying to improve how it solves block linear systems. Before, I had a subroutine `amux` used for sparse matrix-vector multiplication and another subroutine `cg` which implements the conjugate gradient method using `amux`. I wrote a new matrix-vector subroutine `block_amux` and likewise a new solver `block_cg`. By all rights, the new method should run faster, but instead it runs 10 times slower.

In order to track down the problem, I used the profiler gprof to see what was going on. I found that 92.5% of my code was spent running the `cg` subroutine -- even though I never called it, and relied exclusively on block_amux and block_cg. To muddy the waters even further, I put a print statement in the actual `cg` routine saying "Hello world"; it was never printed. Finally, I noticed that gprof lists no uses of the `amux` subroutine, even though a genuine call to cg would have done hundreds of ordinary matrix multiplications.

I'm mystified as to what could be doing this. Any thoughts? I can attach the gprof output if that helps too.

Update: I have made the following changes, with the same result some way or other:

1. Change the names of the subroutines, for example `cg` becomes `conjugate_gradient`. Gprof then reports that I'm wasting time in the new conjugate_gradient routine.
2. Move the subroutines that I actually use into my main program under a "contains" statement instead of the module `linalg_mod` in which they originally resided, then stop using the module containing the CG routine. Instead, the program wastes time in something called a "frame_dummy". This looks suspiciously similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444847/what-does-frame-dummy-mean-in-the-context-of-profiling), but I can't
3. Move the subroutines I use from `linalg_mod`, which contains the CG routine, to a new module `linalg_mod_decoy`, which does not contain it. Instead of wasting time in the CG algorithm, gprof says that the program is calling a subroutine I use to generate the right-hand side of the linear system ~3000 times instead of just once.
4. Try it on a different computer. No difference.

Comment: What happens if you rename the 'cg' subroutine as 'dontcallthissubroutine' or something? This is the kind of situation in which I tend to discover that there's a problem in the makefile and I'm not compiling and running what I thought I was.

Comment: The thought had occurred to me. I renamed it to 'conjugate_gradient', got rid of all executable, object and module files, then rebuilt everything with the same result. gprof reports spending the same amount of time on the weird subroutine, with the name changed of course. I'll try playing around with how everything is compiled though.

Comment: You probably already know this, but be sure to wipe out your old object files and any libraries you have created before you re-compile.

Comment: Any chance your slow version of the executable is stuck in cache?  Have you tried running from a new terminal session?  Or the on/off switch?

Comment: Is it compiled with OpenMP? I've run into problems with gprof and openmp codes. If it is what happens when you compiler without openmp?

Comment: You say you first noticed the slow execution before using `gprof`, so I don't think the profiling itself is causing this, but did you correctly compile as well as link with profiling enabled? Did you try `gdb` for further diagnosis, as also suggested in that post?  Or to compile with a different compiler? Is it possible to post a minimal example that still causes these issues for you?

Comment: Which compiler do you use and what optimisation flags are in effect? Your problem sounds very much like what happens after inlining and/or interprocedural optimisation. Inlining and IPO should be disabled whenever one compiles an instrumented binary.

Comment: OpenMP was the culprit. I figured that if I set the number of threads to 1 I would get the same result as profiling without OMP at all. When I stopped compiling with OpenMP it still performed poorly but correctly reported where all the work was being done. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @korrok I have converted your comment into an answer, to make sure it is preserved. (I landed here because the [linear] tag is currently being replaced by more sharply defined tags, and questions with it are being reviewed.)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [a comment by korrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223534/fortran-erroneously-calls-a-subroutine#comment51438230_14223534), the question author:

> OpenMP was the culprit. I figured that if I set the number of threads to 1 I would get the same result as profiling without OMP at all. When I stopped compiling with OpenMP it still performed poorly but correctly reported where all the work was being done.